# If Statements not being recognized by Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I have been developing on a Application that requires the use of If-Statements, however, Xcode seems to skip right over the "If" part of the If-Statement and goes straight into the "Else" part of the If-Statement. It completely ignores the actual restrictions of the If-Statement and avoid them by jumping right over it, it seems. I see this in all my If-statements such as the one below:

```
if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
    NSLog(@"Logged In!");
} else {
    NSLog(@"Invalid Credentials");
}
```

I do know for a fact that when I go to the PHP link to check for credentials it does return "1" if they are correct and "0" if it isn't, so I know the variables are correct.

Another Example:

```
if ([_username.text isEqualToString:@""] || [_password.text isEqualToString:@""]) {
    //Invalid Credentials
}
```

All help is appreciated! Thank You So Very Much! And Happy New Year!

Comment: Don't "go to the PHP link". Put a breakpoint and inspect your `strResult`, or NSLog it right before your condition.

Comment: Can u add the code for strResult

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you know for a fact that some PHP code returns "1"? Do you also know for a fact that this "1" ends up in strResult? No spaces around it? You make the beginner's mistake of thinking that your code is right and something magical stops it from working. Instead your attitude should be: I made a mistake. Where did I make the mistake?

Setting a breakpoint on the if statement would be a good first step to find your bug.

Seriously, if the compiler couldn't get a simple if-statement right, would anybody be using it?

Comment: Found it my mistake! I didn't see what it was returning in my breakpoints!

Answer (score 0):

I think there is something else wrong.  Your if statement is fine.

I made this version of your code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  SimpleTest
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        NSLog(@"Hello, World!");

        NSString* strResult = @"0";

        if ([strResult isEqualToString:@"1"]) {
            NSLog(@"Logged In!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Invalid Credentials");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It prints out "Logged In!" as expected.  If I make the value of strResult "0", it prints out "Invalid Credentials."

So you must have something else going on.  Print out strResult.  What is it?  is it nil?

Comment: Yep, turns out there was something else going on in the background after checking my Breakpoints!